# Why does named function not work? - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to create a http server using node.js.
This works for me:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
console.log(req.url);
res.end('Hello Node.js');
});

server.listen(3000);***
```

But this throws an error:

```
const http = require('http');
function onRequest(req, res) {
   console.log(req.url);
   res.end('Hello World');
};

const server = http.createServer(onRequest(res, res));
server.listen(3000);
```

I get the following error:
code

```
 ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\socket-first-project\index.js:3:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

It should be the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createServer` expects you to pass it a function.

You are immediately *calling* `onRequest` and passing its *return value* … or would be if you had defined `res` which you are trying to pass to it as an argument (twice!).

```
const server = http.createServer(onRequest);
```

Compare:

```js
function myFunction(anArgument) {
    return anArgument;
}

const argument = 1;

console.log(typeof myFunction);
console.log(typeof myFunction(argument));
```

Comment: Makes total sense! Thank you so much. I will accept answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

On the second to last line you have added `res` twice instead of `(req, res)`. Try replacing the first `res` with `req`.

Comment: While that is a typo (which would justify a close vote rather than an answer if it solved the problem) and not what the OP *intended* to write; it won't solve the problem because what the OP intended to write was wrong.